# Using typescript to get type of field without creating an instance

Tags: typescript

I have this:

```
const _fakeInstance = ({} as any as MutationResolvers).register;
export type RegisterType = typeof _fakeInstance;
```

which feels very awkward, and that there should be a way to do this without creating a (fake) instance first

Comment: `({} as any as MutationResolvers).register` - isn't this `undefined` all the time?

Comment: Wouldn't `export type RegisterType = MutationResolvers['register']` work for you?

Comment: @zerkms  thanks, that is the answer! if you post it, I can mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export type RegisterType = MutationResolvers['register']
```

that way you can extract the property type directly from the `MutationResolvers` type without making dummy instances.